# Graphic chart alignment in VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some Chart Objects in a Microsoft Word document and I want to align it to the center using VBA code. What is written downside seems to work OK, because it detects the Graphic Charts properly, but then I don't know how to center it.

```
Sub CenterChart()
Dim n As Integer, i As Integer
Dim graf As Object
n = Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
If n <> 0 Then
    For i = 1 To n
        Set graf = Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i)
        If graf.HasChart Then
            'Here the code to align to center 
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `InlineShapes` the formatting commands are the same as for text - you use centered paragraph alignment. For example

```
    If graf.HasChart Then
        graf.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Else
    End If
```